# SQL select with if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want select with when or if statement

```
select 
    ID, name,Departmen, date, clock_in, clock_out,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, on_duty, clock_in) as late,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, off_duty, clock_out) as Early,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, on_duty, clock_in) - DATEDIFF(MINUTE, off_duty, clock_out) as total_telat when late <=30 from kkpsurabaya
```

I want make `total_telat` only count 1-30min

Comment: No idea what you mean. Please be more specific

Comment: i want try make more specific. i mean total telat only count if late 1-30min

Comment: sorry, tried to help but your post and your comment on my (deleted) answer don't clearly outline your issue. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: do you only want to see records `WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, on_duty, clock_in) <= 30` or do you only want the column to return a value when it's less than or equal to 30? if the latter, you could do `CASE WHEN  DATEDIFF(MINUTE,on_duty, clock_in) <= 30 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,on_duty, clock_in) END - DATEDIFF(MINUTE ,off_duty, clock_out )  as total_telat` which will just produce a null value if late > 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `CASE . . WHEN . .  END`

```
select  ID, 
    name,
    Departmen, date, clock_in, clock_out,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, on_duty, clock_in ) as late  ,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, off_duty, clock_out ) as Early,
    CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, on_duty, clock_in ) < 30
    THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,on_duty, clock_in ) - DATEDIFF(MINUTE ,off_duty, clock_out ) 
    END as total_telat
from    kkpsurabaya
```

Answer (score 0):

Case statement is closest to if and supported through out all version. this is just an example for your understanding. I hope studying about case will help you achieve what you need.

```
SELECT CAST(
             CASE 
                  WHEN  (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,on_duty, clock_in ) - DATEDIFF(MINUTE ,off_duty, clock_out ))> '0' or (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,on_duty, clock_in ) - DATEDIFF(MINUTE ,off_duty, clock_out )) < '31' 
                     THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 
             END AS bit) as Saleable, * 
FROM Product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT ID
        ,NAME
        ,Departmen
        ,DATE
        ,clock_in
        ,clock_out
        ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, on_duty, clock_in) AS late
        ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, off_duty, clock_out) AS Early
        ,total_telat = iif(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, on_duty, clock_in)<= 30, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, on_duty, clock_in) - DATEDIFF(MINUTE, off_duty, clock_out), NULL)
    FROM kkpsurabaya
```